# Cannot assign the output of "python -V" to a variable in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I'm writing a shell script that do some work after checking the version of python on the system.

and I do a=`python -V` and a echo of $a:

```
[root@machine folder]# a=`python -V`
Python 2.3.4
[root@machine folder]# echo $a
```

and `echo $a` just output nothing

at the same time I do:

```
[root@machine folder]# if grep "2.3.4" `python -V` ; then echo "bad" ; fi
Python 2.3.4
```

after I hit enter it just output the version of the python but nothing else.

Why it behaves like this? Is there other ways for me to do the same task?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`python -V` appears to output on `stderr`. If you run

```
a=`python -V`
```

the output appears on the console (i.e. it's not being picked up by the subshell assignment). However, if you redirect `stderr` to stdout, then

```
a=`python -V 2>&1`
```

works

Comment: Thank you! I never think that it will output to stderr. Great lesson!

Comment: It's not an intuitive use of stderr, granted

Answer (score 1):

Is it worth actually asking Python via `sys` ?

```
 python -c "import sys; print sys.version_info[0:3]"

 (2, 7, 3)
```

As that way one can check version values other than just checking for a version.

```
pyver=$(python -c "import sys; print sys.version_info[0:3]")
required="(2, 7, 1)"
echo pyver=$pyver

if [[ "$pyver" > "$required" ]] ; then
    echo safe to proceed
else
    echo  require Python version ">" $required got $pyver
fi

required="(3, 0, 0)"
if [[ "$pyver" > "$required" ]] ; then
    echo safe to proceed
else
    echo  require Python version ">" $required got $pyver
fi

#-- use integer values --
echo  Integer version
# Trouble being the output looks odd but allows use of -gt
pyver=$(python -c "import sys; print '%03d%03d%03d' % sys.version_info[0:3]")
required="002007001"
echo pyver=$pyver

if [[ $pyver -gt  $required ]] ; then
    echo safe to proceed
else
    echo  require Python version $required got $pyver
fi

required="003000000"
if [[ $pyver -gt $required ]] ; then
    echo safe to proceed
else
    echo  require Python version $required got $pyver
fi
```

Output on my system with Python version 2.7.3

```
pyver=(2, 7, 3)
safe to proceed
require Python version > (3, 0, 0) got (2, 7, 3)
Integer version
pyver=002007003
safe to proceed
require Python version 003000000 got 002007003
```